# trigger to prepopulate a new case with value from it's parent account (trigger not working)

Tags: apex, trigger

could someone point out what I'm missing in this trigger.

```
trigger getTargetDateFromAccount on Case (before insert,after insert) {
    Set<id>accountIds = new Set<id>();

    for(Case acase:trigger.new){
        accountIds.add(acase.account.id);    
    }

    Map<Id,Account> acct = new Map<Id, Account>([select Target_Due_Date__c from Account where Id in :accountIds]);

    for(case acase:trigger.new){
        Account accounts = acct.get(acase.id);
        acase.Case_Target_Date__c = accounts.Target_Due_Date__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not working in any of the 2 scenarios(before and after)?...why are you doing this with a trigger when it can be done with a workflow or formula?

Comment: In a before insert trigger, relationship references evaluate to null. It should read acase.accountId rather than acase.account.id

Comment: @pepeFloyd - this is more for educational purpose on writing triggers, that's why I didn't use a workflow.

Comment: @techtrekker - thanks for the explanation. i will make the changes and provide feedback.

Comment: it is a before trigger and an after trigger (it should probably be one or the other). In either case, the key to the account map is an account id and the code is attempting to retrieve it using a case id so that will not work.

Comment: Using @techtrekker's suggestion I changed the trigger to a before insert trigger and changed the way I was trying to retrieve the values as below:                          `Account accounts = acct.get(acase.accountid);`
`acase.Case_Target_Date__c = accounts.Target_Due_Date__c;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it's not working is because the key to your map acct is the account id, but when you try to retrieve values from the map you are using the case id, so it never returns anything.

Instead of

```
Account accounts = acct.get(acase.id);
```

you should have

```
Account accounts = acct.get(acase.accountid);
```

Edit -- as techtrekker has pointed out you should use accountid rather than account.id in your trigger.

Comment: thanks for the response. will implement that and give you feedback.